# greenDao ORM Query метод

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, orm

использую для работы с БД GreenDao ORM и у меня возник вопрос: у меня есть вот примерно такой RecyclerView
[image: RecyclerView]
<sub>(источник: [androiddocs.ru](http://androiddocs.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/recycler.png))</sub>
  Каждый item имеет свой id начиная с 0. **Вопрос:** как мне в зависимости от нажатого пункта (id) доставать нужную информацию с БД? Например когда кликнули на id 0 то перешли на второе Activity и   с базы вытащили такое описание "Это описание id 0", кликнули на id1 , перешли на то же самое  Activity только описание уже будет например таким "Вы находитесь на активити с описанием id1" и т.д.
Когда я работал просто с *Sqlite* я писал примерно так:

```
   public  String getInfromation(int id) {
    myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = "_id = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id+1)};
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME , null , selection , selectionArgs , null , null , null);
    String str = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() >= 1) {
        do {
            str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("mushroom"));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    myDataBase.close();
    return str;
}
```

И в том активити где нужно было доставать инфу просто вызывал этот метод:

textView.setText(db.getInfromation(id));
  Можно ли так само сделать query запрос в greenDao?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно. Читайте [документацию](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/). Получение элемента по id будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
daoSession.getXXXDao().load(id);
```

После у найденного элемента получаете нужную информацию и устанавливаете ее в TextView.

Если нужен более сложный запрос, то используйте [QueryBuilder](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/).

В графическом режиме создавать бд нет необходимости даже без использования ORM. Бд создается автоматически если ее ещё не существует. В случае с GreenDao вы описываете сущности, которые будут представлены таблицами, после чего генерируются специальные классы, которые будут обеспечивать сохранение, обновление, удаление, выборку данных.

Например вам надо хранить данные о каком то объекте ABC. Тогда сначала надо описать этот объект в генераторе, например так

```
Entity currency = schema.addEntity("ABC");
currency.addIdProperty();
currency.addStringProperty("name");
currency.addStringProperty("description");
```

После чего будут сгенерированны классы: DaoMaster, DaoSession, ABCDao и ABC. Для сохранения данных в бд надо сначала создать объект ABC, заполнить его данными и сохранить через `daoSession`.

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.setName("someName");
abc.setDescription("someDescription");

daoSession.getABCDao.insert(abc);
```

Comment: спасибо ,  но остаеться еще множество вопросов, например как мне наполнять БД? РАньше я качал SqliteDataBrowserPortable  и в графическом режиме создавала таблицу, копировал в проект в папку assets тут же нужно програмно все делать, и чтобы заполнить например столбец description , нужно это всё делать через например метод setDescription  с сгенерированого класса или как? у меня же будут много записей так куча раз писать метод setDescription ?

Comment: @M-Misha-M дополнил ответ

Comment: О, да да я так и сделал , а сам код для query где прописывать, в каком классе? В сгенерированых или какой то свой создать? или сразу можно в MainActivity?

Comment: @M-Misha-M не понимаю о какой "код для query" вы имеете ввиду. Есть класс QueryBuilder который скрывает от вас формирование запроса и возвращает объекты в зависимости от того, какие методы вы вызвали  у него. Если нужно написать какой то свой сложный запрос, то пишите его где то в коде и используете ```daoSession.getDatabase().rawQuery()```. Где это все вызвать, решать вам.